# Octave error : no such file

Tags: octave

I'm running Octave 4.0.1 on windows 7 and I'm having this weird issue.

I created a functioning script which is saved under C:/User/Documents/Octave. This script also reads some files in a subfolder of this same location.
The problem is : my script correctly runs TWICE then I have the error "no such file" saying the software did not find my script (the same one I just ran). The only "solution" I have is restarting the whole software but then it still goes nuts on the third run.

In addition to that, my coworker tried it on an ubuntu machine and it seemed to work fine. Do somebody see an explanation?
Thanks

Here is the script :

```
data = [];
figure();
for i=1:200
  filename = strcat('C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Octave/data/DAQ_data_decoded_', num2str(1800+i))
  d=lvm_import(filename);
  data=[data d.Segment1.data(:,2)];
end;

data=reshape(data,6600,1);
hist(data);
```

The function lvm_import is a function I found on the web to extract data from a Labview data file. (d.Segment1.data(:,2) is a 33x1 array)

And the error message :

```
>> daqDataHist
error: no such file, 'C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Octave\daqDataHist.m'
```

Comment: You have to create a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Make it as small as possible yet it shows the error

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the path can't be `C:/User/Documents/Octave`.

Comment: Your script is probably changing paths and not resetting your working directory back to where it was before you ran the script.  Please show us what the script looks like.

Comment: The complete path is C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Octave, I just wrote it in a shorter way that I thought to be comprehensible.
Regarding an example of code, it is irrelevant because the problem is not in the code but in the software losing track of the script file.

Comment: The script looks really gross in a comment so I'll edit it into the main post.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the path can't be `strcat('C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Octave/data/DAQ_data_decoded_', num2str(1800+i))`. Have you tried using backslashes?

Comment: Where did `lvm_import` come from? The software can't "lose track" of your script. It's not sentient. As @rayryeng said, there's very likely a `cd` somewhere that is not properly returning to the original path.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you post the *actual* error message rather than paraphrasing it so we can see whether the issue is finding the script or finding the data file.

Comment: As you guys suggested, I tried using backslashes -but same result- and I put the error message in the main post. Also, `lvm_import` comes from the mathworks file exchange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19913-lvm-file-import)

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't really know what was going on but by adding `fclose all` at the end of the script I got rid of any error and can run the file as many times as I want. It was probably something going wrong with opening and closing the `.lvm` files and it "jammed" at some point.
Thanks anyway :)